# Deciphering Skoda handbook

Tags: windshield-wipers, skoda, service-manual, fabia

My mum's new Skoda Fabia has some obscure instructions relating to the windscreen-wipers.

It says "tip-wiping" - what on earth is that?

And it refers to the "sprung position" - is this the stem pressed away from the driver or pulled towards, or what?

Any help please - I can't find any mention of "tip-wiping" online.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've not heard of "tip-wiping" either. Could you by chance give us some context to the term? I take it this is in the wiper section (lol)? Any other context?

Comment: It refers to the finger **tip** single-wipe operaration, where the control lever is tipped/tapped/moved against a spring. The other positions (slow, continuous, fast) are not sprung: the lever stays where it is put. In my Octavia, that is a tap in in the downward direction, with the other settings in the upward direction. I suggest sitting in the car with the handbook and trying things out.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, I think that is probably correct. I would have sat in the car but unfortunately I wasn’t with the car. I personally am not in the habit of referring to manuals but my 70+ year old mum had got herself in a state worrying about it! I think your theory is correct. Add your comment as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm glad you're baffled as well! Seems like Weather Vane is familiar with the parlance. A little clarification for the non-initiated would have been a nice inclusion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the finger **tip** single-wipe operaration, where the control lever is tipped/tapped/moved against a spring.

The other positions (intermittent, normal, fast) are not sprung: the lever stays where it is put.

In my Skoda Octavia, the lever is tapped in the downward direction to get a single wipe. The other settings are in the upward direction.